# directive link function execution order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-layout

I'm kind of new in all this angular...

I have a custom directive, lets call it myDar.
Inside this directive I define a link function.
In my html I want to to use multiple nested tags of this directive as follows:

```
<myDar id="outer"><myDar id="inner"></myDar></myDar>
```

I want the link function of "outer" to be executed first. How do I do this?

That's the general question.
If it helps then what I'm really trying to do is to create directives that wrap jquery ui layout ([link to the website](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)). So I have a directive for "ui-layout" and directives for "center", "west" etc.
In the "ui-layout" directive I call to `$(tElm).layout(options)`. 
I have a problem when creating a nested layout:

```
<ui-layout class="layout-container">
    <ui-layout-center>
        <ui-layout>
            <ui-layout-center>inner center</ui-layout-center>
            <ui-layout-west>inner west</ui-layout-west>
        </ui-layout>        
    </ui-layout-center>
    <ui-layout-west>west</ui-layout-west>
</ui-layout>
```

Angular executes first the link function of the inner "ui-layout" directive but for the jquery ui layout plugin to work it requires to call `$(tElm).layout(options)` of the outer first, otherwise the layout is not rendered correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain in details what you need to run in which linking function?

Comment: Btw `angular.module('app').directive('myDar' ...` will register myDar as snake-case in the html `<my-dar>...</my-dar>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you will take advantage of the directive's controller. It will be a *class* defining a method to register nested controllers and another one for executing the desired command (here `$(...).layout(...)`) on this element *and then on all of its children*. This means that the outer directive is responsible for coordinating the creation of the layouts.

The full example code is:

```
app.directive("y", function() {
    function Controller($element) {
        this.$element = $element;
        this.children = [];
    }

    Controller.prototype.register = function(child) {
        this.children.push(child);
    };

    Controller.prototype.execute = function() {
        console.log("PAYLOAD: " + this.$element.attr("id"));
        for( var i=0; i < this.children.length; i++ ) {
            this.children[i].execute();
        }
    };

    return {
        require: "y",
        controller: ["$element", Controller],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var e = element.parent(), nested = false;
            while( e != null ) {
                if( e.controller("y") != null ) {
                    e.controller("y").register(ctrl);
                    nested = true;
                    break;
                }
                e = e.parent();
                if( typeof(e.tagName) === "undefined" ) break; //XXX Needed, at least for fiddle
            }
            if( !nested ) ctrl.execute();
        }
    };
});
```

Replace the line `console.log("PAYLOAD: " + this.$element.attr("id"));` with the actual code to run. See relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xSjZ/

If the outer directive was different than the current, getting the parent controller would be as easy as requiring `"?^y"`. In this case, it gives us the current controller, therefore we have to loop (`e.parent()`) ourselfes.

Comment: Great answer. One question: how does the e.controller("y") work? Does this directly call the constructor of the Controller class?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Actually `e.controller()` is an Angular extension to jqLite (or jQuery). It is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) - look for "jQuery/jqLite Extras". What it does in short is that it finds an *existing* controller with the given name, attached to the element. So it does *not* call the constructor, it expects the controller to be already constructed and attached to the element.

Comment: One more question: Consider I do not have nested a directive, so I have something like <div level="1" id="a" y=""> followed by another <div id="other" level="2" y="">. While processing the first div in the link function, I would like to access the second div using angular.element("div[level='2']") and subsequently the controller using .controller("y"). See this plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/oIpvQP. I get a JQLite exception "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element"

Comment: You would have to include jQuery for this, so that Angular uses jQuery instead of jQlite. jQlite is an implementation of a cut-down version of the jQuery API. It does not support this kind of selector (i.e. `"div[level='2']"`). I *guess* there should be some other way to do this by *reorganizing* your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact use case a `compile` function might be a good fit. `compile` functions are executed before `link` functions and - what's more important - in reverse order. Meaning parent first.

```
app.directive("ui-layout", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
               //do layout stuff here
               //return a link function or nothing
```

Another solution could be to execute the relevant code of your child directives using `$timeout`.

```
app.directive("ui-layout-center", function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
              //do layout stuff later
             }, 0);
```

Comment: The no-second $timeout did the trick for me since it defers to the next digest cycle.